# How to write to the SSO from BizTalk during run time

Tags: single-sign-on, biztalk

I have a requirement where I have to write a value to the SSO store during run time.  I found a lot of blogs about reading from the SSO but having no luck in finding a blog that talks about writing to the SSO during run time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a method to call [ISSOConfigStore.SetConfigInfo(String, String, IPropertyBag) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.enterprisesinglesignon.interop.issoconfigstore.setconfiginfo?view=bts-2020) added to the helper class for SSO

The below code as per T Hemani's/theman post on MSDN/Technet

```
 public static void Write(string appName, string propName, string propValue)
         {
             try
             {
                 ISSOConfigStore configStore = (ISSOConfigStore)new SSOConfigStore();
                 ConfigurationPropertyBag appMgmtBag = new ConfigurationPropertyBag();
                 object tempProp = propValue;
                 try
                 {
                     appMgmtBag.Remove(propName);
                 }
                 catch { }
                 appMgmtBag.Write(propName, ref tempProp);
                 configStore.SetConfigInfo(appName, idenifierGUID, (IPropertyBag)appMgmtBag);
             }
             catch (Exception e)
             {
                 System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(e.Message);
                 throw;
             }
         }
```

Comment: See the solution that worked for me at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d1f2acc9-73c6-490c-a0b8-cb00e5a943fa/how-to-write-to-the-sso-from-biztalk-during-run-time?forum=biztalkgeneral&prof=required